# Eclipse Error on Mavericks: posix_spawn is not a supported process launch mechanism on this platform

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, osx-mavericks

I'm using OS X Mavericks. I've installed apple's Java and JDK 8 and 7 from Oracle. Downloaded Android ADT. When I run eclipse, it shows me this error on build. I couldn't use eclipse.

Do you have any idea about that problem?

> An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace". posix_spawn
>   is not a supported process launch mechanism on this platform.

```
java.lang.Error: posix_spawn is not a supported process launch mechanism on this platform.
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:105)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:94)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<clinit>(UNIXProcess.java:92)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.execAapt(PreCompilerBuilder.java:1225)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.handleResources(PreCompilerBuilder.java:1123)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.build(PreCompilerBuilder.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: I've solved this problem by simply unistalling Java JDK 8 from my system. Then Eclipse will use JDK 7 by default and problem will be solved.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is special language characters (Probably i-İ in Turkish as in this case).

**Here is how I solved step by step:**

1. Change your preferred language to English as primary. ([How to?](http://youtu.be/guodhyHnltA?t=1m22s))
2. Restart Mac.
3. Start Eclipse and create a project.  (Your problem should have been
       solved right now)
4. Close eclipse.
5. Change your preferred language to
   Turkish.
6. Restart Mac.

*Since the problem is only faced by Turkish users, I will also add translation of above as:*

---

Problem dildeki özel karakterler (Muhtemelen Türkçe'deki i-İ harfi, bu durumda).

**Adım adım çözüm:**

1. Sistem dilinizi İngilizce'ye çevirin. ([Nasıl mı?](http://youtu.be/guodhyHnltA?t=1m22s))
2. Mac a restart atın.
3. Eclipse i açın ve proje oluşturun.  (Sorununuz bu aşamada çözülmüş olması lazım)
4. Eclipse i kapatın.
5. Sistem dilinizi Türkçe'ye çevirin.
6. Mac a restart atın.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for now is to run with -Djdk.lang.Process.launchMechanism=fork until this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uninstalling the new JDK you can configure eclipse to use specific jdk by manipulating *Eclipse.app/Contents/info.plist*

Open info.plist with a text editor and add below line (I am adding 1.6.0 since I use jdk6, if you want to use jdk7 use 1.7.0)

```
<string>-vm</string><string>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Commands/java</string>
```

in the beginning of **array** tag

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
    <array>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can configure Run Configuration if you want and pass vm argument as 
"-Duser.language=us"

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Mac OS 10 with Java SDK 1.8.0. Updating Java SDK solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You had already solve your problem but If problem can occur again, change your region to USA. This is because of Turkish language's I and İ is different than English.

Comment: When you say "change your region" do you mean in under Language & Region in OS X's System Preferences? Or somewhere else? (I have a Turkish customer experiencing crashes triggered by ProcessBuilder (not Eclipse-related).)

Comment: @Adrian yes. Please say your client to change your region settings. I am pretty sure that it is related Turkish alphabet which is causing trouble. (Turkish I --> ı, English I --> i this is the main reason behind the problem. Java bean convention uses uppercase, lowercase by system settings and Java can not find necessary getter, setter methods.)

Comment: I was able to code around this Java bug, which was preferable to making the client change their settings. (And in fact, I couldn't reproduce the problem using region settings anyway.) I'll just link to my article about this, since it's not directly relevant to the original question: http://java.thedizzyheights.com/2014/07/java-error-posix_spawn-is-not-a-supported-process-launch-mechanism-on-this-platform-when-trying-to-spawn-a-process/