# Mac os after 10.9.3 Android Studio is not working

Tags: java, android, macos

I have a new Macbook pro. My computer update OSX 10.9.3 in yesterday.
When I try run a new Android Project, I get this gradle error.

```
Error:Could not initialize class java.lang.UNIXProcess
```

[image]

When I sync project gradle some time  get this error.

```
Error:Cause: posix_spawn is not a supported process launch mechanism on this platform.
```

Please help.
Thanx.

Comment: What is the output of "/usr/libexec/java_home -V" in Terminal?

Comment: @SteveC Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Olkun-MacBook-Pro:~ olkunmustafa$     1.7.0_55, x86_64:"Java SE 7"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
-bash: 1.7.0_55,: command not found
Olkun-MacBook-Pro:~ olkunmustafa$     1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64:"Java SE 6"/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
-bash: 1.6.0_65-b14-462,: command not found
Olkun-MacBook-Pro:~ olkunmustafa$     1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386:"Java SE 6"/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
-bash: 1.6.0_65-b14-462,

Comment: Does your user account have admin privileges?

Comment: I uninstall JDK_7 and my problem is solved. Thank you

Comment: you could solve the problem right this way tho:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28474254/1281930

Answer (score 4):

1. Right Click on Android Studio from your install location
2. Click Show Contents
3. Open Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions with any text editor
4. Add -Duser.language=en to the end of the file.
5. Save
6. Run Android Stuio.

It will work well...